# Debian: Disable software Raid?

Tags: debian

I own a server with 2 hdds and I used a debian raid installation template.
Know I want to reinstall my server and don't want raid anymore to have more space.
My provider wants money to change the template to a non-raid debian one.

Is there a way to disable software raid on linux after a fresh installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes a mdadm based Raid 1. It is a very general answer, as you haven't really provided much details on the actual setup.

To un-raid a software Raid 1 you do the following:

1. Remove one of the disk/partitions from the raid device, putting it in a degraded mode.
2. Create a fresh partition, filesystem etc on the freed drive. Rsync all files from the degraded raid device to the new partition.
3. If /boot/ is handled by a raid device, repeat 1 and 2 on it as well.
4. Fiddle with /boot/grub/menu.1st and /etc/fstab to make sure the system is booted without the degraded raid device(s).
5. Reboot
6. Clear away the degraded raid from the remaining disk.

(Preferable by first practicing on a local, possibly virtual, test system.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it tomorrow after I've reinstalled my server. And yes I'm using mdadm.

Answer (score 0):

Andol's answer is correct for a RAID-only setup.

If the system uses lvm+raid, however, you can do a 'live' move of your filesystems (assuming RAID-1 or RAID-10):

- remove half your disks from the raid array (one mirror)
- on each disk, create one partition, set type to Linux LVM
- run `pvcreate` on those partitions
- run `vgextend` on your existing lvm volume group with the partitions as argument (e.g., `vgextend /dev/vg0 /dev/sda1`)
- for each of your lvm logical volumes, run `pvmove -v /dev/md0` (assuming that's the name of your RAID device), and wait until they've finished
- reinstall your bootloader as soon as the vg containing `/boot` has been fully moved
- once all LVs have been moved, run `vgreduce -a`. This should remove the raid array from your lvm vg. If it doesn't, that means there's still data on the RAID.
- you can now destroy the RAID array, add the other disks to the volume group, and possibly resize your LVs.